# node-gcm cordova android custom sound push

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugins

I have a project on CORDOVA. Connected to it FCM.
The instructions indicate that I can set my sound to a notification.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-refa

[image]

On the server (node.js), I am using the node-gcm module. The documentation also says that you can set the sound

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gcm

In the project itself, the sound file is in several places (just for the sake of the case):

cordova-root/

1. test.mp3 res/raw/test.mp3
2. res/android/raw/test.mp3
3. platforms/android/res/raw/test.mp3
4. platforms/android/app/src/main/res/raw/test.mp3

After the assembly, I checked for the presence of sound in the APK file along the path res/raw/test.mp3 - it is there.

I am sending a message from the server. It is successfully displayed on the smartphone, BUT SOUND DEFAULT. Not the one I set.

Question: How do I get messages to arrive with the right sound?
Testing for ANDROID 9

```
var message = new gcm.Message({
  notification: {
    sound: 'test',
    title: "TITLE",
    body: "BODY",
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting Android 8, there is a thing called [NotificationChannel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel) which determines the notification priority, sound, vibration patterns and LED color. There is an eternal conflict between these **channel settings** and the **push payloads**, and no one seems to know for sure which one takes precedence over the other.

The settings for a notification channel cannot be changed neither from the `PushNotification.createChannel` method nor the push payload. In my tests, things like the sound and LED color cannot be overriden by the push data. (you can, however, set a vibration pattern in the payload, and it will be respected by the plugin if you have created a channel with `vibration` activated).

My guess is, you'll have to [create a new notification channel](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushnotificationcreatechannelsuccesshandler-failurehandler-channel) with the custom sound name, then send the push with the same sound (or none for that matter). Remember that once created, some channel settings **cannot be changed** even if you delete the channel and re-create it with the same ID. My advice is to forget about modifying the default `PushPluginChannel` because it's a waste of time: use new channels with your preferred settings, and start testing what happens with:

- Sound file set in payload vs. sound file set by createChannel
- Vibration set in payload vs. vibration set by createChannel
- LED color set in payload vs. LED color set by createChannel

You'll have plenty of fun trying to figure out how these settings work in Samsung phones with Android 8 and other phones with Android 9. I almost went mad trying to set the LED color in the Samsung phone, but it worked after altering the plugin (v2.1.3).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I did not find anything about LED in the documentation for phonegap-plugin-push, can it be set in the createChannel() parameters?

Comment: @АлександрМиронов Yes you can set the color in createChannel but this is not documented. Don't forget to upvote useful answers here please.

Comment: Please tell me how to do this? I can’t do it.  for example
PushNotification.createChannel(
  ()  => '',
  ()  => '',

  led: true, // does not work
  lights: true, // does not work
  light: true, // does not work
  ledColor: [0, 0, 255, 0], // does not work
  lightColor: [0, 0, 255, 0] // does not work
)

Comment: @АлександрМиронов I believe I am in the same boat.  I think the problem lies with getting the notification sent to the Channel you have created in the ionic app.  I have not been able to find out where this is set in node-gcm